# docker-compose not reading environment variables on Ubuntu inside WSL

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Docker project that needs environment variables to run. It runs well on Unix based systems, but now I am running it in WSL inside a Windows 10 machine and they are not working.

I have a file with environment variables `.envrc` that looks like this:

```
export VAR_1=var1
export VAR_2=var2
```

On Ubuntu, inside WSL, if I run `source .envrc` , the variables are loaded properly on Ubuntu.

If I run `printenv` , all the variables are loaded and listed as expected.

On my `docker-compose.yml` file, the variables are accessed as follows:

```
  VARIABLE_1: ${VAR_1}
  VARIABLE_1: ${VAR_2}
```

For some reason the variables are not loaded properly when I use `docker-compose up my_container` .

If I hardcode the variables on the `docker-compose.yml` file, they are loaded with no problem.

```
  VARIABLE_1: var1
  VARIABLE_1: var2
```

Is there any other configuration I need to do to make sure that the variables are loaded properly?

Comment: Are you running `source .envrc` _before_ running `docker-compose up`? Are you running `docker-compose` from a WSL shell?

Comment: Yes, I am running source .envrc before running docker-compose up and yes, I am using a WSL shell to get into bash inside Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with line endings on Windows messing up with Linux. I just needed to save the `.envrc` file using a text editor configured for Linux.

To find out the solution:

I used `printenv` to check if the environment variables were properly loaded in Linux.

Then I used `docker-compose config` to make sure Docker was picking the variables up from the environment.

These commands allowed me to see that Linux was picking up the `\r` carriage return from Windows and that was causing the problem.